How to monitor the boot process for headless Jetson Orin via USB?
I've connected my Ubuntu 22 host to nru-220s-nvidia-jetson-orin via a USB-A to USB-C cable. I used Minicom to connect to /dev/ttyACM0, and that works OK.
I can also connect via SSH, so this USB connection does not bring anything new.
I'd like to use Minicom (or other tool?) also to monitor the Jetson boot process - is this possible at all? While booting, there is no /dev/ttyACM0 yet, until the boot is finished, so nothing to connect to.

Try the USB-C port, it is mentionned as debug-only in the datasheet of your NRU220S, run minicom or putty or else from host (might be /dev/ttyUSB device probably framing 115200 8N1) and reboot the Jetson, you may see the early boot.
